# BERT encodings from TensorFlow hub

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am using the following code to generate embeddings for my text classification.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
bert_preprocess =hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4")
def get_sentence_embeding(sentences):
    preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(sentences)
    return bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)['pooled_output']
e = get_sentence_embeding(["happy", "sad"])
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity([e[0]],[e[1]])
```

the above gives array([[0.99355495]], dtype=float32)
it is saying similarity score between happy and said is 99%
why it is given 99%? can I use these embeddings for my text classification?

Answer (score 0):

BERT wasn't optimized to put words with contrary meanings far away from each other in the embedding space. Instead, the two words are close together since both are adjectives.

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert) tutorial actually demonstrates how to fine-tune BERT for sentiment analysis.